# Should I say "very praising" and "very serious"?

Tags: word-usage, antonyms

I have four terms, as follows:

```
Polite, Friendly, Serious, Praising
```

**First question: By the method of adding prefixings, are the opposites of them:**

```
Impolite, Unfriendly, Unserious, Unpraising
```

**Secondly, if I want use two adverbals to define them by two levels, like "very" and "fairly" (I don't know whether they are idiomatic if put these two adverbals before them), should I say:**

```
Very polite - fairly polite - fairly impolite - very impolite
Very friendly - fairly friendly - fairly unfriendly - very unfriendly
Very serious - fairly serious - fairly unserious - very unserious
Very praising - fairly praising - fairly unpraising - very unpraising
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'Praising' just doesn't belong in this list. Some '-ing' adjectives can be used in this way - we can easily say 'very exciting - fairly exciting - fairly unexciting (or fairly boring) - very unexciting (or very boring)', but not 'praising'.
Basically, '(im)polite', '(un)friendly' and '(un)serious' are adjectives, and 'exciting' can be used as an adjective. 'Praising', as far as I can think, can only be used as a verb ('The teacher was praising her students') and a gerund ('Praising students can make them study harder'), but not as an adjective (*'The praising teacher was very happy' - but compare ?'The praised students studied harder').
By the way 'unserious' is not commonly used. The spell checker here does not recognise it, but a Google search shows that it exists.

Comment: The normal way of saying "unserious" is "not serious" (you can use "not very serious" instead of "fairly unserious", and "not serious at all" instead of "very unserious"). https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unserious%2Cnot+serious&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunserious%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20serious%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Oh, I see, thx!